# How to create a mysql query that checks if a row exists - if it does I want to insert a new record otherwise increment a value

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has an `ID` and an `occurrences` column. I want to create a single transaction to the db where

```
if ID exists in DB:
    occurrences++
else:
    insert new row where occurrences = 1
```

I saw that it's possible to do an IF THEN statement so I was attempting to do something like this:

```
IF ID = 123 IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE occurrences = occurrences +1
ELSE
    INSERT INTO entity_table(123, 1)
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO entity_table SET id=123, occurrences = 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurrences = occurrences + 1
```